How do I include CSS in a XWiki rendering Macro written in Java?
How can I include CSS in a XWiki rendering Macro written in Java (XWiki-Version: 16.8.0)?
It seems that a while ago "SkinExtension" was used for somthing like this, but that does not seem to be the right option nowadays.
I do not want to embed the CSS in the output of the Macro, but would prefer to "register" the CSS somehow globally.
